# Updating Data into empty rows from different tables and summarizing the quantities using dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following is the query updating data into a table of empty rows from other connected columns and then summarising the quantities of each with respect to dates.

```
Update Dis 
    set Dis.OpStk = Sum(Case when ST.TrDate < FDate then ST.Qty end),--Quantity of stock before FDate
    Dis.ClsStk = Sum(case when ST.TrDate >TDate then ST.Qty end ),--Quantity of stock After TDate
    Dis.B14 = Sum(Case when Dis.FDate=DateADD(day,-14,FDate) then SL.Qty end),--Before 14 days
    Dis.A14 = Sum(Case when Dis.TDate=DATEADD(day,14,TDate) then SL.Qty end),--After 14 days
    Dis.A28 = Sum(Case when Dis.TDate=DATEADD(day,28,TDate) then SL.Qty end),--After 28 days
    Dis.A60 = Sum(Case when Dis.TDate=DATEADD(day,60,TDate) then SL.Qty end),--60
    Dis.A180 = Sum(Case when Dis.TDate=DATEADD(day,180,TDate) then SL.Qty end) --180
from #DisData Dis
Inner Join StockLine ST on Dis.ItemCode=ST.ItemCode 
Inner Join SaleLine SL on Dis.ItemCode=SL.ItemCode
```

from these linked tables

My question is this query correct. If no then what is the correct form.

Comment: This isn't MySQL syntax

Comment: _updating data into a table of empty rows_ if your table is empty, there is nothing to update

Comment: @Strawberry this is MS SQL

Comment: So please tag your question appropriately

Comment: @nacho Updating rows in a half empty table so it would be update not INSERT

Comment: What do you mean by "is it correct"? Does it work? Does it accomplish what you want to accomplish? Your comment character is wrong, for SQL Server its `--` not `#`.

Comment: @DaleK I haven't run it yet because if i do i think it would mess my table up if it is not correct.I am very beginner to this.So kindly tell me the right code if it is not correct

Comment: @DaleK Let me test it then first thanku

Comment: When you do come with a question, you need to specify what you are trying to accomplish - normally with some sample data (as DDL+DML), your desired results (as formatted text) and your query attempt.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "My question is this query correct?" is not a question this community can answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

The query is not correct.  It is not correct in *any* database, because of the `SUM()` in the `SET` clause.  That is not allowed in SQL Server.  It is not allowed by SQL in general.

Your question is unclear on what you intend to accomplish.  You might be surprised, but a non-working query often does not contain such information.

I suspect that you want something like this:

```
Update Dis 
    set OpStk = st.opstk,
        . . .
        B14 = sl.b14,
        . . .
from #DisData Dis cross apply
     (select Sum(Case when ST.TrDate < dis.FDate then ST.Qty end) as OpStk,
             . . . -- additional expressions here
      from StockLine ST 
      where Dis.ItemCode = ST.ItemCode 
     ) st cross apply
     (select Sum(Case when Dis.FDate = DateADD(day, -14, dis.FDate) then SL.Qty end) as b14,
             . . . -- additional expressions here
      from SaleLine SL 
      where Dis.ItemCode = SL.ItemCode
     ) sl;
```

I do note that YOUR date arithmetic uses `=`, but the comments use words like "before" and "after".  So, this will probably succeed in updating the table, but may not do what you really want.